# What is the most hackable Roomba?

Tags: robotics, roomba

I gotta get a [Roomba](http://www.irobot.com/) because the dog hair builds up faster than I can get to vacuum it but I also want to make a beer bot that can go and fetch beer from the [kegorator](http://www.kegerator.com/). Seems the [Roomba](http://www.irobot.com/) is the perfect base and since I usually only drink on special occasions (read: the weekend) I think a dual purpose [Roomba](http://www.irobot.com/) would be perfect.

I know there is a "developer Roomba" but it doesn't come with a vacuum. Is it (relatively) easy to add a usb connector to any [Roomba](http://www.irobot.com/)?

Answer (score 5):

The 4000 series has a serial port that uses a special connector (it looks like an SVideo port) that is easily accessible.  On the newer ones you have to remove the cover it looks like.  [Website descriptions here](http://hobbymechatronics.com/projects/30-robotics/8-diy-roomba-usb-interface-cable).

The [commands can be found here.](http://www.irobot.com/images/consumer/hacker/Roomba_SCI_Spec_Manual.pdf)

You'll probably want something wireless to control it remotely and it looks like [Sparkfun has you covered for $100](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/684).That will present itself as a serial port via bluetooth if I read it correctly.

I'm not sure your Roomba will be able to get the beer though, but that's just a few dozen hacks away :)

Comment: I'm checking out the links now . . . but this looks promising. Note that, in order to get it to fetch beer I'm going to try and get the Roomba to work with the Google's arduino compatible ADB device just announced at Google I/O. I think that has bluetooth built in so I can send commands using my phone. If not, I may need to connect a phone to the arduino and use another phone to send commands.  I still have a ton of research to do as you can tell!

Comment: That PDF mentions that ALL Roombas have a serial port! Crazy!